# Immediately Complete Animations -- jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm working on a project which requires me to animate a single object 2-3 times simultaneously without queueing any of them. The animations run as follow:

```
jQuery("#Object").animate({'left': '0px', 'top':'0px'},{duration:0,queue:false});
jQuery("#Object").animate({'left':xPosition,'top':yPosition},{duration:Time, queue: false});
```

I've been tring to figure out how to get the second position animation to stop mid-execution and reset back to point (0,0). Since the object is a spritesheet, I'm also running:

```
 jQuery("#Object").animate({'background-image-x':'0px'},{duration:0,queue:false});
 jQuery("#Object").animate({'background-image-x':nextFrame},{duration:0,queue:false});
 // ^this second one is to be set to an interval of some kind, or run in a loopback anim function
```

Again, I'm trying to get the animations to reset and play again.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you use animate() with duration equal to 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the .stop() method: http://api.jquery.com/stop/